# Create a feature, scenario, and its steps at runtime

Tags: python, python-behave

I'm using python-behave to run some test. For a "proof-of-concept" project I would like to create a test (feature/scenario) at runtime.

I'm gathering the test steps from a web server and try to build a `Scenario` object. One idea was to use the `before_all` hook to get the steps from the server and compile them together. But I cannot find an example of how to make a `scenario` or `step` object.

`get steps as strings from server` --> `compile/build scenario` --> `run test/scenario`

Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I did it the other way around. I imported the behave main and called it with a file I dynamically write.

```
from behave.__main__ import main as behave_main
...
behave_main(['-i', 'myDynamicTest.feature', ...])
```